# Unable to force a click of a hidden element with Capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have an intermittent failure in my capybara tests caused by a modal not closing quickly enough and so covering the button that is to be clicked.  The error message from Capybara tells me to try `node.triger('click')`.  When I try this with the following code

```
find_button('Update').trigger('click')
```

I get this error:

```
 Failure/Error: find_button('Update').trigger('click')

 Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
   Capybara::Driver::Node#trigger
```

I am using the poltergeist driver e.g. in my rails_helper I have

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need a request or animation to finish in order for the next test to work, a solid strategy is to write a test that causes Capybara to wait until it passes. For example, if your modal with selector `.modal` disappears after clicking an OK button, you could write a test like:

```
click_button 'OK'
expect(page).not_to have_css '.modal'
click_button 'Update'
```

By default, Capybara waits for two seconds for animations and async requests to finish before failing a test. That can be configured with `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5` to change it to 5 for example.

Comment: This answer is perfect until the last line of code which should just be `click` (Or click_button) not trigger('click')

Answer (score 1):

As sometimes happens, just by writing the question out, I found the answer. In the particular test in question, I had not set `js: true`. Another test in the same file where I received the original error message, did have `js: true`.  Once I set `js: true` in all the tests in the file, I did receive consistent error messages and could use ```.trigger('click').

Comment: `.trigger('click')` should be a method of last resort since it allows you to do things a user never could which negates the whole point of writing tests in the first place. See the answer by mroach for the correct solution (but just using click rather than trigger)